# How to retrieve a list of disk devices from Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, logging, device

In *Windows Server 2012R2* *Event Viewer* shows error ID 15:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        disk
Date:          9/29/2014 3:16:49 PM
Event ID:      15
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      server.name
Description:   The device, \Device\Harddisk6\DR82, is not ready for access yet.
```

Where do I find a list of these devices? These hard disks? How can I find more details about which disk is throwing the error?

Comment: You could try SNMP

Comment: @captcha I'm not sure what you're referring to. Would you explain, please?

Comment: SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) can be added as a service to Windows. With an SNMP client you can then query all sorts of information of a system, such as all the various disks and their details. You could see if the SNMP names for your disks give you the information you want. It may be a long shot..